# Combining two CTEs with UNION causes an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Getting the following error:

> 'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.'

When running the CTE's separately it's fine. But when combining using a UNION.. then the error appears.

```
With cte1 as 
(
    select
       .
       .
       .

    Select

    from

)
select

UNION

With cte2 as 
(
    Select

    From
)
Select 

from
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server, CTEs are attached to the outermost `select`.  In other words, there is only one per query and all the definitions must come before the `select`.

So combine them into a single `with`:

```
with cte1 as (
      select . . . 
     ),
     cte2 as (
      select . . .
     )
select . . .
from cte1 . . . 
union
select  . . 
from cte2 . . .;
```